# useHistory function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm having a problem where my code does not want to work while redirecting to the main page which is Dashboard.js. That file is just an UI I'm working on. I'm currently working on a signup and login page. Here is the code.

`Signup.js`

```
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Signup() {
  const emailRef = useRef()
  const passwordRef = useRef()
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
  const { signup } = useAuth()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const history = useHistory()

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match")
    }

    try {
      setError("")
      setLoading(true)
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
      history.push("/")
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to create an account")
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

`AuthContext.js`

```
import { auth } from "../firebase"

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  function logout() {
    return auth.signOut()
  }

  function resetPassword(email) {
    return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
  }

  function updateEmail(email) {
    return currentUser.updateEmail(email)
  }

  function updatePassword(password) {
    return currentUser.updatePassword(password)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setLoading(false)
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    signup,
    logout,
    resetPassword,
    updateEmail,
    updatePassword
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

`Login.js`

```
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Login() {
  const emailRef = useRef()
  const passwordRef = useRef()
  const { login } = useAuth()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const history = useHistory()

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      setError("")
      setLoading(true)
      await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
      history.push("/")
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to log in")
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Log In</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Log In
            </Button>
          </Form>
          <div className="w-100 text-center mt-3">
            <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</Link>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        Need an account? <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react"
import Signup from "./Signup"
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap"
import { AuthProvider } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard"
import Login from "./Login"
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute"
import ForgotPassword from "./ForgotPassword"
import UpdateProfile from "./UpdateProfile"

function App() {
  return (
    <Container
      className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
    >
      <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
        <Router>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/update-profile" component={UpdateProfile} />
              <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
            </Switch>
          </AuthProvider>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App
```

`index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./components/App"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

The problem I'm having in this code is at the useHistory part in Login.js(Line 12 and 21) and Signup.js(Line 13 and 26). Included  the other codes because I think that all of the code might be linked to one another.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you describe your problem exactly what is happening as of now and what should be happening in ideal condition? Are you not able to go back to previous pages using "History"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both login and signup scenarios you are redirecting to home page immediately after a successful call. However your context value is updating only when the onAuthStateChanged function callback is called by firebase. There can be a small lag during this time and hence you aren't able to redirect to the PrivateRoute correctly.

A reliable way of handling this would be to wait for the currentUser data to be available from context like

```
 const { login, currentUser } = useAuth()
 async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      setError("")
      setLoading(true)
      await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to log in");
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      if(currentUser) {
          history.push('/');
      }
  }, [currentUser]);
```

A similar handling can be done in signup component too. This way even if you try to visit the login or signup routes directly from browser url, you will be redirected to home page if the user is already logged in.