# UseEffect to fetch user number and pass to CurrentUser state on unsubscribe (order of execution)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, use-effect

I'm using Firebase to authenticate a user, then using the Firebase ID (uid) to setUserData with the user's row in Postgres via a HTTP request. It works as written, but I'm having trouble with the order execution of these functions because the console is returning 'invalid input syntax for type integer: "undefined"'.

The desired order is

1. Wait for the authentication to return a uid
2. Execute the HTTP request using uid
3. Redirect to "/"

Instead, it seems to run 2, 1, 3, 2. On the second HTTP attempt data is populated. This explains why I sometimes need to log out and log back in for certain components to load with the user's data.

What am I missing to ensure correct order of operations?

**Login.js**

```
   async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        try {
          setError("")
          setLoading(true)
          await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
          setLoading(false) 
          history.push("/")   
        } catch {
          setLoading(false)  
          setError("Failed to log in")
        }
```

**Auth.js**

```
   useEffect(() => {

        const fetchProfile = (uid) => {
            axios.get(`/user/${uid}`)
            .then(async (response) => {
                setUserData(await response.data)
                console.log(response.data)
                console.log(uid)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
        }

        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
            user && fetchProfile(user.uid)
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        })

        return unsubscribe

    }, [])

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        userData,
        login,
        signup,
        logout,
        resetPassword,
        updateEmail,
        updatePassword
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            { !loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove `fetchProfile` as a function and move `unsubscribe` outside of `useEffect` and have `currentUser` as a dependency to `useEffect`. `useEffect` would only run when `currentUser` has changed.

```
...
const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
        //only if there is a user setCurrentUser
       if(user){
         setCurrentUser(user)
         setLoading(false)
       }
   })

useEffect(() => {
        if(!currentUser) return
        axios.get(`/user/${currentUser.uid}`)
          .then(async (response) => {
              setUserData(await response.data)
              console.log(response.data)
              console.log(uid)
          })
          .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
    }, [currentUser])
...
```

Comment: This works too, but unsubscribe is never called and I need to set state to null on logout somewhere because when I sign out and log in, the console is printing the previous uid then the current uid. Any ideas?

Comment: Aahh makes sense. But `onAuthStateChanged` is a listener that would be called when initializing `unsubscribe`. Calling `unsubscribe` cancels the listener from listening to changes. Removing conditional `if(user)` and `setCurrentUser` on every auth change should work.

Comment: You can also remove the assignment `unsubscribe` and call `onAuthStateChanged` directly.

Comment: I'm closer with your suggestions, but still having issue with order of operations. Login.js is executing the `login` function onclick then redirecting immediately without waiting for the `useEffect` to update the user's uid. I've seen a few posts about this issue with the firebase sdk but don't know the solution.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `history.push` to the resolve of the `axios` call?

Comment: Solved using methodology in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793542/usehistory-function-in-reactjs